# jquery make entire empty div clickable

Tags: jquery, css

I have this code:

```
var appendColors = function(colors, root) {
    $.each(colors, function(index, value) {
      var swatchEl = $('', {
          'class': 'swatch'
        })
        .css('background-color', 'rgba(' + value + ', 1)');
      root.append(swatchEl);
    });
```

This routine creates a series of div with a class of "swatch".
The class 'swatch' simply contains width: 40px; height: 20px;

Each div is assigned a background colour.
The colours are passed into the script via the variable 'colors'

I want to be able to make each div 'clickable'. ie... something like this

```
$('.swatch').html('execute jquery script');
```

What I really want is for users to be able to click in the div
None of the divs will contain any anchor text
so the entire 'empty' is clickable

When they click on the div, a jquery call will change the colour of another div called 'targetDiv' to the same colour background colour of the calling div.

Sorry if this doesnt make sense.
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will update the background color of an element with the background color of the clicked element:

```
$(".swatch").click(function() {
    $("#target").css('background-color', $(this).css('background-color'));
});
```

[See a working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/3xLnmnfs/2/)

Since none of the divs will contain any text, it is important to give them height and width to make them visible. Otherwise, you won't see the color updates. See the CSS on the linked JSFiddle for ideas.

Comment: Using starting script, can you tell me how to make the cursor change to pointer when hovered over the 'swatch' divs

Comment: $('<div>', {'class': 'swatch'}).css('cursor', 'pointer');............this doesn't work for me

Comment: The easiest way is to do it in your CSS: `#swatchContainer div {cursor: pointer}`. If you must do it in JavaScript, just adjust your selector: `$('#swatchContainer div').css('cursor', 'pointer')`

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's `on` function like:

```
$.(".swatch").on('click',function(){

  //code to change color of div

 });
```

Comment: thanks for your response.  I agree with your suggestion